# Java NIO filekey structure

Tags: java, posix, nio

What are a `dev` and `ino` in NIO's `fileKey` String representation?
I saw similar questions, but didn't find any description about what those keys are exactly are

Comment: Are you referring to interface [`java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) ?

Comment: @Abra, yes, I am

Answer (score 0):

It is a `unique identifier`, to more info [fileKey()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#fileKey--)
here is the code

Let me show you with an example in both Windows OS and Linux OS.
The code is the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Path.of("resources/test_en.properties");
    BasicFileAttributes basicFileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    System.out.println(basicFileAttributes.fileKey());
}
```

When I execute this code in Windows OS, I get **null** as a result

Let's execute this code in Linux, to do this, I installed WSL on Windows. After that install Java 11 in your subsytem (You can find a lot of resources on the Internet how you can setup Java 11 on WSL)
I assume you have installed Java 11, then create a demo file by executing below command

```
touch hello.txt
```

after that, execute following command

```
ls -i
```

and you will get file name and its unique identifier, it is called **inode**

here is the result

```
 49539595901185150 hello.txt
```

Result probably will be different in your computer

Then create a new java file and add above Java code into it, but change the file path in the code like following
[image]

Compile the code and execute, you will get the result of the `fileKey()` method
[image]